# Realm/Monarchy: Add item header to paged list

Tags: android, kotlin, realm, pagedlist

I have a realm database and I am loading a huge list from it and display it with monarchy and PagedListAdapter. That all works fine, but now I want to update the PagedList to insert some header items.
My problem is that the `add` methods of PagedList are not implemented.
My current code:

```
val monarchy = Monarchy.Builder().build()
val realmDataSourceFactory = monarchy.createDataSourceFactory { realm -> realm.where<Customer>().sort(RealmCustomer::lastName.name) }
val dataSourceFactory = realmDataSourceFactory
        .map { it.toCustomerListItem() }
customers = monarchy.findAllPagedWithChanges(realmDataSourceFactory, LivePagedListBuilder(dataSourceFactory, 50))
```

and in the Activity

```
val adapter = CustomerAdapter()
viewModel.customers.observe(this, Observer { pagedList ->
    pagedList?.let {
        adapter.submitList(it)
    }
})
customerListRecyclerView.adapter = adapter
```

Where can I/do I need to add the header items?

Comment: This is a general limitation of Positional data sources from the Paging library; the best solution I have is to use https://github.com/edubarr/header-decor which adds header-items as ItemDecoration.

Comment: Good idea. I added the header to the item-views and view/hide them as needed.